# Netbeans and build error when including jna.jar and jna-platform.jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, jna

C:\NetBeansProjects\EnvironmentSwitcherApplet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:835: Problem creating jar: central directory zip64 extended information extra field's length doesn't match central directory data.  Expected length 0 but is 16

Goes away when I remove the jna.jar files.

Comment: Sounds like the Jar might be corrupt

Comment: Odd - it compiles - just won't deploy.  I'll try downloading again, and also try generating it from the source.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - downloaded again - still didn't work - but unzipped it and rezipped it - and it did.  Put it in as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it sounds like the Jar might be corrupt or is using a compression that Java doesn't recognize...